# Convert plain numbers from file to list of integers

Tags: python, list, text

I have a text file with some plain numbers that i want them as integers in a list.
For example i'd like this
`299 314 427`
to be converted to this
`list = [[299], [314], [427]]`
i read the text file
`with open('C:/...', 'r') as f:`
`masses= f.read()`
and then i use a for loop and spectra.split(' ') since a blank space is the only thing that separates the integers but it appeds to list every number separately

```
list = []   
masses.split(' ')  
for mass in masses:  
    list.append(mass)
```

the results is ['2','9','9',' ','3',......]
how can i split them and append them in list ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```
>>> with open('FILEPATH') as f:
...     lst = [[int(n)] for n in f.read().split()]
... 
>>> lst
[[299], [314], [427]]
```

Without argument, [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.split) splits strings by consecutive whitespace (space, tab, newline, ..):

```
>>> 'a\t\tb\nc  d'.split()
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> 'a\t\tb\nc  d'.split(' ')
['a\t\tb\nc', '', 'd']
```

Don't use `list` as a variable name. It shadows the builtin function [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list).

Comment: amazing! it worked. also you are right for list i was going to rename it. but why you left split() without parameters is the one space ' ' the default split ?

Comment: @fractal_7, without argument, `str.split()` splits by all whitespaces (space, tab, newline, ..). I edited the answer to mention that with an example.